# Angular: can't import Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

in my angular app there is no syntax error.

In a file called **test1.js** I have only one line

```
var express = require('express');
```

but here is my error log

(literally for this one line, if I comment it out everything is good)

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\cookie-signature'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\content-disposition'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\serve-static'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\angular_practise\restTest5\node_modules\body-parser\lib'
```

[ note that : i already did `npm i express --save` ]

[ another interesting thing is : if I run the .js file as node.js app ( `node test1.js` ) , everything works fine ]

Please point out what went wrong, i can't find any clue.

Comment: You have something messed up in your installation.  I don't know if it's some module in node_modules or something with your actual installation of node.js itself.  I think you need to clean up and reinstall some stuff.  Maybe start with a clean reboot first.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok i will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a client-side SPA framework designed to run in a web browser.

Express is an server-side framework designed to be the foundation of a web **server** and run through Node.js.

**You cannot run Express inside a web browser** (and thus as part of an Angular deployment). The APIs required (such as access to the filesystem (`fs`) and binding HTTP networking ports (`http`) are not available.

It *isn't* possible to `require`/`import` Express code into the client-side Angular program.

If Express and Angular are to be combined, it is as two separate programs where Express is used to host the compiled Angular program over HTTP and/or provide web services for it to call.

Comment: So, how can I show something from express to angular? Can you give me an example of any library that can act as a middle man between them?

Comment: @Frost — By making a web service call to an HTTP server created using Express.

Comment: which library should I use?

Comment: XMLHttpReqest maybe?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this. can you give me a tutorial or any blog link that has example for a situation like this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest